# How to call a function within a function in netlogo, whereby both functions will take multiple arguments?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to call a function within a function in netlogo and both functions take a number of arguments, how can I do that? before I even try runresult (from previous answers), the code syntax is giving me many errors.

Essentially, what the code is doing is driving a forward reaction: species1 + species 2 -> species 3 by doing the following:

asking species1 to scan the perimeter for species2, and if found, based on a an onrat (k-on) multiplied by a factor (alpha), make species 2 die and set the breed of species1 to species3. Now, second function (set-attributes2) will be called tos et certain attributes of the new species3, which takes many arguments too. How do I:

1. call a function2 (set-attributes2) within a function1(fwd-reaction)
2. pass arguments of function2 (for example )when doing the above?

```
to set-attributes2 [ x-occupiedepitopes x-size x-leader x-exempt_from_immobilisation x-aggregated x-color]
  set occupiedepitopes x-occupiedepitopes
  set size x-size
  set leader x-leader
  set aggregated x-aggregated
  set exempt_from_immobilisation x-exempt_from_immobilisation
  set color x-color
end


to fwd-reaction [#asking-species #species-to-scan #x-k_on #x-alpha #species-to-die #new-breed]
  ;let temp-list []
  ;set temp-list (list asking-species species-to-scan x-k_on x-alpha species-to-die new-breed )
  let scanning #species-to-scan
  ask #asking-species [
    if (any? other (#species-to-scan) -here) and random-float 1000 < (#x-k_on * 2 * #x-alpha)
      [
            ask one-of other #species-to-die -here
            [ die ]
            set breed #new-breed
            set-attributes2 0 2 self true false red

          ]
        ]
      
end
```

Right now, the error says I am missing a paranthesis after -here in this line of code:

```
 if (any? other (#species-to-scan) -here) and random-float 1000 < (#x-k_on * 2 * #x-alpha)
```

Comment: `other turtles-here with [breed = #species-to-scan]`?